# LAB, RGB, XYZ Color Conversion Incorrect Vice versa

Tags: vb.net, colors, xna, rgb, cielab

I'm making a custom color-picker for a project, it's in photoshop style, i got all the other conversions to work as expected but i can't get RGBToLAB and LABToRGB to work correctly.

The problem is not just that the colors are not represented correctly but that the conversion isn't perfect too.

Sample :

- LAB _ 58:0:0
- XYZ _ 0.25960986510312:0.25960986510312:0.25960986510312
- RGB _ {R:10 G:8 B:7 A:255}
- XYZ _ 0.250358161840588:5.51162077338675:66.3836625496266
- LAB _ 85.3739502460609:0:0

The initial LAB is not the same as the last LAB, this shows that the conversion is flawed. Not only am i getting the wrong colors but there's a change in values, especially when LAB.L is suppose to be constant(in this example, because that's what the slider currently is controlling)

The LAB->RGB->LAB conversion above is flawed but so is the XYZ->RGB->XYZ conversion too.

Obviously i'm not interested in converting LABToLAB but the above does point out a flaw in the conversion.

Things i've tried :

1. [This formula on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#Forward_transformation)
2. [EasyRGB's code](https://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php)
3. [This javascript code on github](https://github.com/antimatter15/rgb-lab/blob/master/color.js)
4. [This cginc code intended for unity, which is where i'm at now](https://gist.github.com/mattatz/44f081cac87e2f7c8980)

   ```
      Private Function LABToXYZ(LAB As LAB) As XYZ
       Dim X, Y, Z As New Double

       Y = ((LAB.L + 16.0) / 116.0)
       X = ((LAB.A / 500.0) + Y)
       Z = (Y - (LAB.B / 200.0))

       Dim Less = 0.206897

       If (X > Less) Then
           X = Math.Pow(X, 3)
       Else
           X = ((X - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
       End If
       If (Y > Less) Then
           Y = Math.Pow(Y, 3)
       Else
           Y = ((Y - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
       End If
       If (Z > Less) Then
           Z = Math.Pow(Z, 3)
       Else
           Z = ((Z - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
       End If

       Return New XYZ(X, Y, Z)
   End Function

   Private Function XYZToRGB(XYZ As XYZ) As Color
       Dim R, G, B As New Double
       Dim X, Y, Z As New Double

       X = (XYZ.X / 100)
       Y = (XYZ.Y / 100)
       Z = (XYZ.Z / 100)

       R = ((X * 3.2406) + (Y * -1.5372) + (Z * -0.4986))
       G = ((X * -0.9689) + (Y * 1.8758) + (Z * 0.0415))
       B = ((X * 0.0557) + (Y * -0.204) + (Z * 1.057))

       Dim Less As Double = 0.0031308

       If (R > Less) Then
           X = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(R, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
       Else
           X = (R * 12.92)
       End If
       If (G > Less) Then
           Y = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(G, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
       Else
           Y = (G * 12.92)
       End If
       If (B > Less) Then
           Z = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(B, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
       Else
           Z = (B * 12.92)
       End If

       Return New Color(CSng(X), CSng(Y), CSng(Z))
   End Function

   Private Function RGBToXYZ(Color As Color) As XYZ
       Dim RGB = ColorToRGB(Color)
       Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
       Dim Less As Double = 0.04045

       If (RGB.R > Less) Then
           X = Math.Pow(((RGB.R + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
       Else
           X = (RGB.R / 12.92)
       End If
       If (RGB.G > Less) Then
           Y = Math.Pow(((RGB.G + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
       Else
           Y = (RGB.G / 12.92)
       End If
       If (RGB.B > Less) Then
           Z = Math.Pow(((RGB.B + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
       Else
           Z = (RGB.B / 12.92)
       End If

       X = (((X * 0.4124) + (Y * 0.3576) + (Z * 0.1805)) * 100.0)
       Y = (((X * 0.2126) + (Y * 0.7152) + (Z * 0.0722)) * 100.0)
       Z = (((X * 0.0193) + (Y * 0.1192) + (Z * 0.9505)) * 100.0)

       Return New XYZ(X, Y, Z)
   End Function

   Private Function XYZToLAB(XYZ As XYZ) As LAB
       Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
       Dim L, A, B As New Double
       Dim Less As Double = 0.008856

       X = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))
       Y = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))
       Z = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))

       If (X > Less) Then
           X = Math.Pow(X, (1.0 / 3.0))
       Else
           X = ((7.787 * X) + (16.0 / 116.0))
       End If
       If (Y > Less) Then
           Y = Math.Pow(Y, (1.0 / 3.0))
       Else
           Y = ((7.787 * Y) + (16.0 / 116.0))
       End If
       If (Z > Less) Then
           Z = Math.Pow(Z, (1.0 / 3.0))
       Else
           Z = ((7.787 * Z) + (16.0 / 116.0))
       End If

       L = ((116.0 * Y) - 16.0)
       A = (500.0 * (X - Y))
       B = (200.0 * (Y - Z))

       Return New LAB(L, A, B)
   End Function

   Function ColorToRGB(Color As Color) As RGB
       Return New RGB((Convert.ToInt32(Color.R) / 255), (Convert.ToInt32(Color.G) / 255), (Convert.ToInt32(Color.B) / 255))
   End Function
   Public Class RGB
   Public ReadOnly Min As Double = 0
   Public ReadOnly Max As Double = 1

   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(R As Double, G As Double, B As Double)
       Me.R = R
       Me.G = G
       Me.B = B
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(Color As Color)
       Me.R = (Convert.ToInt32(Color.R) / 255)
       Me.G = (Convert.ToInt32(Color.G) / 255)
       Me.B = (Convert.ToInt32(Color.B) / 255)
   End Sub

   Private _R As New Double
   Private _G As New Double
   Private _B As New Double

   Public Property R As Double
       Get
           Return _R
       End Get
       Set
           _R = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Property G As Double
       Get
           Return _G
       End Get
       Set
           _G = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Property B As Double
       Get
           Return _B
       End Get
       Set
           _B = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Overrides Function ToString() As String
       Return (_R.ToString & ":"c & _G.ToString & ":"c & _B.ToString)
   End Function
   End Class

   Public Class XYZ
   Public ReadOnly Min As Double = 0
   Public ReadOnly Max As Double = 100

   Public Sub New()
   End Sub

   Public Sub New(X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double)
       Me.X = X
       Me.Y = Y
       Me.Z = Z
   End Sub

   Private _X As New Double
   Private _Y As New Double
   Private _Z As New Double

   Public Property X As Double
       Get
           Return _X
       End Get
       Set
           _X = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Property Y As Double
       Get
           Return _Y
       End Get
       Set
           _Y = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Public Property Z As Double
       Get
           Return _Z
       End Get
       Set
           _Z = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Overrides Function ToString() As String
       Return (_X.ToString & ":"c & _Y.ToString & ":"c & _Z.ToString)
   End Function
   End Class

   Public Class LAB
   Public ReadOnly Min As Double = -128
   Public ReadOnly Max As Double = 127

   Sub New()
   End Sub

   Sub New(L As Double, A As Double, B As Double)
       Me.L = L
       Me.A = A
       Me.B = B
   End Sub

   Private _L As New Double
   Private _A As New Double
   Private _B As New Double

   Property L As Double
       Get
           Return _L
       End Get
       Set
           _L = LimitInRange(Value, 0, 100)
       End Set
   End Property

   Property A As Double
       Get
           Return _A
       End Get
       Set
           _A = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Property B As Double
       Get
           Return _B
       End Get
       Set
           _B = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
       End Set
   End Property

   Overrides Function ToString() As String
       Return (_L.ToString & ":"c & _A.ToString & ":"c & _B.ToString)
   End Function
   End Class

   Function LimitInRange(Value As Double, Min As Double, Max As Double) As Double
       Select Case Value
           Case <= Min
               Return Min
           Case >= Max
               Return Max
           Case Else
               Return Value
       End Select
   End Function
   ```

I need the code in VB.Net, that's why i'm working on converting and adapting the unity code for my project, however i am stuck and need some help.

If anybody knows what i'm doing wrong, i'll be glad to listen.

**UPDATE 1:**
I've tried to correct the conversion more by mismatching the two conversion methods, i'm getting closer to a perfect conversion, however i'm afraid that i might have gotten tunnel vision from working on this issue for so long.

Sample :

- LAB _ 0:0:0
- XYZ _ 0.262413383082537:0.262413383082537:0.262413383082537
- RGB _ {R:10 G:8 B:7 A:255}
- XYZ _ 0.250358161840588:0.253536089358344:0.236754082437929
- LAB _ 2.29017121228677:-0.12373260790384:0.261362975778545

As you see the problem is less than before but it's still there.

```
    Private Function LABToXYZ(LAB As LAB) As XYZ
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double

        Y = ((LAB.L + 16.0) / 116.0)
        X = ((LAB.A / 500.0) + Y)
        Z = (Y - (LAB.B / 200.0))

        Dim Less = 0.008856

        If (X > Less) Then
            X = Math.Pow(X, 3)
        Else
            X = ((X - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
        End If
        If (Y > Less) Then
            Y = Math.Pow(Y, 3)
        Else
            Y = ((Y - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
        End If
        If (Z > Less) Then
            Z = Math.Pow(Z, 3)
        Else
            Z = ((Z - 16.0 / 116.0) / 7.787)
        End If

        Return New XYZ(X * 100, Y * 100, Z * 100)
    End Function

    Private Function XYZToRGB(XYZ As XYZ) As Color
        Dim R, G, B As New Double
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double

        X = (XYZ.X / 100)
        Y = (XYZ.Y / 100)
        Z = (XYZ.Z / 100)

        R = ((X * 3.2406) + (Y * -1.5372) + (Z * -0.4986))
        G = ((X * -0.9689) + (Y * 1.8758) + (Z * 0.0415))
        B = ((X * 0.0557) + (Y * -0.204) + (Z * 1.057))

        Dim Less As Double = 0.0031308

        If (R > Less) Then
            R = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(R, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
        Else
            R = (R * 12.92)
        End If
        If (G > Less) Then
            G = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(G, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
        Else
            G = (G * 12.92)
        End If
        If (B > Less) Then
            B = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(B, (1.0 / 2.4))) - 0.055)
        Else
            B = (B * 12.92)
        End If

        Return New Color(CSng(R), CSng(G), CSng(B))
    End Function

    Private Function RGBToXYZ(Color As Color) As XYZ
        Dim RGB = ColorToRGB(Color)
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Dim R, G, B As New Double
        Dim Less As Double = 0.04045

        If (RGB.R > Less) Then
            r = Math.Pow(((RGB.R + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            R = (RGB.R / 12.92)
        End If
        If (RGB.G > Less) Then
            G = Math.Pow(((RGB.G + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            G = (RGB.G / 12.92)
        End If
        If (RGB.B > Less) Then
            B = Math.Pow(((RGB.B + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            B = (RGB.B / 12.92)
        End If

        R *= 100
        G *= 100
        B *= 100

        X = ((R * 0.4124) + (G * 0.3576) + (B * 0.1805))
        Y = ((R * 0.2126) + (G * 0.7152) + (B * 0.0722))
        Z = ((R * 0.0193) + (G * 0.1192) + (B * 0.9505))

        Return New XYZ(X, Y, Z)
    End Function

    Private Function XYZToLAB(XYZ As XYZ) As LAB
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Dim L, A, B As New Double
        Dim Less As Double = 0.008856

        X = XYZ.X / 100
        Y = XYZ.Y / 100
        Z = XYZ.Z / 100

        If (X > Less) Then
            X = Math.Pow(X, (1.0 / 3.0))
        Else
            X = ((7.787 * X) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If
        If (Y > Less) Then
            Y = Math.Pow(Y, (1.0 / 3.0))
        Else
            Y = ((7.787 * Y) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If
        If (Z > Less) Then
            Z = Math.Pow(Z, (1.0 / 3.0))
        Else
            Z = ((7.787 * Z) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If

        L = ((116.0 * Y) - 16.0)
        A = (500.0 * (X - Y))
        B = (200.0 * (Y - Z))

        Return New LAB(L, A, B)
    End Function
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Further testing shows an exceptionally undesired behavior in XNA.Framework.Color, resulting in any fraction being interpreted as a %.
Meaning that 200.10 would be over 200% of the max color value(255), which would cap it at the max value(255), so unless you specify integers you could end up getting a very wrong output.

I'm trying to mismatch the code [from this example as well](http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/RGB-to-L-a-b-Conversion-td3703729.html). I feel that i'm progressing, even if i had to go away from using the XNA.Framework.Color class in the conversions.

I'll update with a final solution if i find one.

**UPDATE 3:**
Online testing [here](http://colormine.org/convert/xyz-to-lab) [(source code here)](https://github.com/THEjoezack/ColorMine/blob/master/ColorMine/ColorSpaces/Conversions/LabConverter.cs) and [here](http://colorizer.org/) shows that my LABToXYZ is incorrect.

My results :

- Lab _ 100:0:0
- XYZ _ 95.047:100:100

Their results :

- Lab _ 100:0:0
- XYZ _ 95.05:100:108.88

  ```
  Public Function LABtoXYZ(LAB As LAB) As XYZ
      Dim X, Y, Z As Double
      Y = ((LAB.L + 16.0) / 116.0)
      X = ((LAB.A / 500.0) + Y)
      Z = (Y - (LAB.B / 200.0))

      Dim Pow_X = Math.Pow(X, 3.0)
      Dim Pow_Y = Math.Pow(Y, 3.0)
      Dim Pow_Z = Math.Pow(Z, 3.0)

      Dim Less = 216 / 24389

      If (Pow_X > Less) Then
          X = Pow_X
      Else
          X = ((X - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
      End If
      If (Pow_Y > Less) Then
          Y = Pow_Y
      Else
          Y = ((Y - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
      End If
      If (Pow_Z > Less) Then
          Z = Pow_Z
      Else
          Z = ((Z - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
      End If

      Return New XYZ((X * 95.047), (Y * 100.0), (Z * 108.883))
  End Function
  ```

But doing LAB with all 0s result in a XYZ with all 0s, which is correct behavior, i can't tell what's wrong, it's Z that's incorrect but where is the error in my code?

Further examples [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/image/1.1.28/image/labToXYZ.html) seems to suggest that my code is correct but i'm still getting an incorrect Z.

**UPDATE 4:**
Further refinement and re-redoing all the code, i've found that a conversion and an adaption of the examples found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19045/Manipulating-colors-in-NET-Part), gave me the results i wanted, even tho there were some errors in that examples, notable the ^2.2 when it should have been ^2.4.

I also found some problems with precision that had to turn doubles into integers for the conversion to be perfect, but this might be the final update, unless i experience any issues, i'll leave this question open for awhile as i continue to test the code in practice.
I will come back and mark it as answered when i'm confident that the code isn't flawed.

Sample :
Test 1

- LAB _ 1:0:0
- XYZ _ 0.105222895807779:0.110706172533356:0.120540201839494
- RGB _ 4:4:4:255
- XYZ _ 0.115400959145268:0.121410793419535:0.132216354033874
- LAB _ 1:0:0

Test 2

- LAB _ 10:0:0
- XYZ _ 1.07024816003116:1.12601992701628:1.22604427713313
- RGB _ 27:27:27:255
- XYZ _ 1.04175693531671:1.09600940064882:1.19355423730657
- LAB _ 10:0:0

Test 3

- LAB _ 100:0:0
- XYZ _ 95.047:100:108.883
- RGB _ 255:255:255:255
- XYZ _ 95.05:100:108.9
- LAB _ 100:0:0

Test 4

- LAB _ 11:0:0
- XYZ _ 1.19854884694432:1.26100649883144:1.37302170612264
- RGB _ 29:29:29:255
- XYZ _ 1.16783071832485:1.22864883569159:1.33799858206814
- LAB _ 11:0:0

As seen above, there's a tiny variation that if not rounded, would cause an imperfect conversion.

**The Classes**

```
  Public Class RGB
        Public ReadOnly Min As Double = 0.0
        Public ReadOnly Max As Double = 255.0

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer)
            Me.R = R
            Me.G = G
            Me.B = B
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer, A As Integer)
            Me.R = R
            Me.G = G
            Me.B = B
            Me.A = A
        End Sub
        Public Sub New(R As Double, G As Double, B As Double, A As Double)
            Me.R = Convert.ToInt32(R)
            Me.G = Convert.ToInt32(G)
            Me.B = Convert.ToInt32(B)
            Me.A = Convert.ToInt32(A)
        End Sub
        Public Sub New(R As Double, G As Double, B As Double)
            Me.R = Convert.ToInt32(R * 255)
            Me.G = Convert.ToInt32(G * 255)
            Me.B = Convert.ToInt32(B * 255)
        End Sub
        Public Sub New(Color As Color)
            Me.R = Convert.ToInt32(Color.R)
            Me.G = Convert.ToInt32(Color.G)
            Me.B = Convert.ToInt32(Color.B)
            Me.A = Convert.ToInt32(Color.A)
        End Sub

        Private _R As New Double
        Private _G As New Double
        Private _B As New Double
        Private _A As Double = 255

        Public Property R As Double
            Get
                Return _R
            End Get
            Set
                _R = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property G As Double
            Get
                Return _G
            End Get
            Set
                _G = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property B As Double
            Get
                Return _B
            End Get
            Set
                _B = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property A As Double
            Get
                Return _A
            End Get
            Set
                _A = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return (_R.ToString & ":"c & _G.ToString & ":"c & _B.ToString & ":"c & _A.ToString)
        End Function

        Public Shared Operator =(Left As RGB, Right As RGB) As Boolean
            If ((Left.R = Right.R) AndAlso (Left.G = Right.G) AndAlso (Left.B = Right.B) AndAlso (Left.A = Right.A)) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator <>(Left As RGB, Right As RGB) As Boolean
            Return (Not (Left = Right))
        End Operator

    End Class

    Public Class XYZ
        Public ReadOnly Min As Double = 0

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(X As Double, Y As Double, Z As Double)
            Me.X = X
            Me.Y = Y
            Me.Z = Z
        End Sub

        Private _X As New Double
        Private _Y As New Double
        Private _Z As New Double

        Public Property X As Double
            Get
                Return _X
            End Get
            Set
                _X = LimitInRange(Value, Min, 95.05)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Y As Double
            Get
                Return _Y
            End Get
            Set
                _Y = LimitInRange(Value, Min, 100)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property Z As Double
            Get
                Return _Z
            End Get
            Set
                _Z = LimitInRange(Value, Min, 108.9)
            End Set
        End Property

        Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return (_X.ToString & ":"c & _Y.ToString & ":"c & _Z.ToString)
        End Function

    End Class

    Public Class LAB
        Public ReadOnly Min As Double = -128
        Public ReadOnly Max As Double = 127

        Sub New()
        End Sub

        Sub New(L As Double, A As Double, B As Double)
            Me.L = L
            Me.A = A
            Me.B = B
        End Sub

        Private _L As New Double
        Private _A As New Double
        Private _B As New Double

        Property L As Double
            Get
                Return _L
            End Get
            Set
                _L = LimitInRange(Value, 0, 100)
            End Set
        End Property

        Property A As Double
            Get
                Return _A
            End Get
            Set
                _A = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Property B As Double
            Get
                Return _B
            End Get
            Set
                _B = LimitInRange(Value, Min, Max)
            End Set
        End Property

        Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return (_L.ToString & ":"c & _A.ToString & ":"c & _B.ToString)
        End Function

    End Class
```

**Converters**

```
Public Function LABtoXYZ(LAB As LAB) As XYZ
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Y = ((LAB.L + 16.0) / 116.0)
        X = ((LAB.A / 500.0) + Y)
        Z = (Y - (LAB.B / 200.0))

        Dim Pow_X = Math.Pow(X, 3.0)
        Dim Pow_Y = Math.Pow(Y, 3.0)
        Dim Pow_Z = Math.Pow(Z, 3.0)

        Dim Less = (216 / 24389)

        If (Pow_X > Less) Then
            X = Pow_X
        Else
            X = ((X - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
        End If
        If (Pow_Y > Less) Then
            Y = Pow_Y
        Else
            Y = ((Y - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
        End If
        If (Pow_Z > Less) Then
            Z = Pow_Z
        Else
            Z = ((Z - (16.0 / 116.0)) / 7.787)
        End If

        Return New XYZ((X * 95.047), (Y * 100.0), (Z * 108.883))
    End Function

    Private Function XYZToRGB(XYZ As XYZ) As RGB
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Dim R, G, B As New Double
        Dim Pow As Double = (1.0 / 2.4)
        Dim Less As Double = 0.0031308

        X = (XYZ.X / 100)
        Y = (XYZ.Y / 100)
        Z = (XYZ.Z / 100)

        R = ((X * 3.24071) + (Y * -1.53726) + (Z * -0.498571))
        G = ((X * -0.969258) + (Y * 1.87599) + (Z * 0.0415557))
        B = ((X * 0.0556352) + (Y * -0.203996) + (Z * 1.05707))

        If (R > Less) Then
            R = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(R, Pow)) - 0.055)
        Else
            R *= 12.92
        End If
        If (G > Less) Then
            G = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(G, Pow)) - 0.055)
        Else
            G *= 12.92
        End If
        If (B > Less) Then
            B = ((1.055 * Math.Pow(B, Pow)) - 0.055)
        Else
            B *= 12.92
        End If

        Return New RGB(R, G, B)
    End Function

    Private Function RGBToXYZ(RGB As RGB) As XYZ
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Dim R, G, B As New Double
        Dim Less As Double = 0.04045

        R = (RGB.R / 255)
        G = (RGB.G / 255)
        B = (RGB.B / 255)

        If (R > Less) Then
            R = Math.Pow(((R + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            R = (R / 12.92)
        End If
        If (G > Less) Then
            G = Math.Pow(((G + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            G = (G / 12.92)
        End If
        If (B > Less) Then
            B = Math.Pow(((B + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)
        Else
            B = (B / 12.92)
        End If

        X = ((R * 0.4124) + (G * 0.3576) + (B * 0.1805))
        Y = ((R * 0.2126) + (G * 0.7152) + (B * 0.0722))
        Z = ((R * 0.0193) + (G * 0.1192) + (B * 0.9505))

        Return New XYZ(X * 100, Y * 100, Z * 100)
    End Function

    Private Function XYZToLAB(XYZ As XYZ) As LAB
        Dim X, Y, Z As New Double
        Dim L, A, B As New Double
        Dim Less As Double = 0.008856
        Dim Pow As Double = (1.0 / 3.0)

        X = ((XYZ.X / 100) / 0.9505)
        Y = (XYZ.Y / 100)
        Z = ((XYZ.Z / 100) / 1.089)

        If (X > Less) Then
            X = Math.Pow(X, Pow)
        Else
            X = ((7.787 * X) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If
        If (Y > Less) Then
            Y = Math.Pow(Y, Pow)
        Else
            Y = ((7.787 * Y) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If
        If (Z > Less) Then
            Z = Math.Pow(Z, Pow)
        Else
            Z = ((7.787 * Z) + (16.0 / 116.0))
        End If

        L = ((116.0 * Y) - 16.0)
        A = (500.0 * (X - Y))
        B = (200.0 * (Y - Z))

        'We solve the precision problem by rounding to nearest integer
        'This makes the conversion perfect.
        Return New LAB(CInt(L), CInt(A), CInt(B))
    End Function
```

Further testing is required before i'll mark this as solved.

**UPDATE 5:** Haven't had any issues so far... I don't know how to mark this as answered when there is only the question posted.
The full free code and more can be found [here](https://github.com/VampireMonkey/GeonBit.UI.Extensions).

Comment: You didn't post the related classes (LAB, XYZ and RGB) which should contain some logic to verify/convert the input values The rounding can cause some not so subtle difference. What is Color (`Return New Color(CSng(X), CSng(Y), CSng(Z))`) in `XYZToRGB`?  Anyway, turn Option Explicit ON, Option Strict ON, Option Infer OFF, fix the issues that rise (for example, `Dim RGB = ColorToRGB(Color)` in `RGBToXYZ` will not (probably) be allowed anymore) and then review the conversions.

Comment: I suggest that you compare,  the EasyRGB code to that of the original cginc code that you tried to convert and your code for LAB2XYZ and XYZ2LAB. Your should discover that the you have some computation  errors in your code.

Comment: @Jimi I updated the question with those classes. I forgot to mention that the "Color" class is the color class in "Microsoft.Xna.Framework", i don't know if that creates any issues from the regular drawing.color.
"Option Infer OFF" didn't do much, the only places the infer broke was where it had inferred correctly anyways.

Comment: Option Infer is less important than Option Strict. The latter, you have to turn on, expecially when you're performing this kind of operations (multiple conversions of type). Option Explicit ON is also important. This should be your default setup. VB.net is not JavaScript. I'll give a look at the updated code as soon I can.

Comment: @Jimi I have all the options on by default, except infer. I'm currently trying to do what TnTinMn suggested, no luck so far.

Comment: I told you that because, pasting your code in my IDE, I had a number of errors and warnings. Some are of course related to the missing classes, some other are not. For example `Dim RGB = ColorToRGB(Color)`. That can only be accepted if Option Strict is OFF. Your LABToXYZ method seems to be missing the illuminants normalization. LabColorspace.cginc code is normalizing the values, EasyRGB is not. It needs to be tested.

Comment: @Jimi i updated the question with further changes, i'll be working on it further today.

Comment: I have not time to check, but try converting white and black. There are various scale for RGB (0...1, 0...100, 0...255, 16...235). The conversion formula could use an other assumption (the 16...235 is very frequent, because of video). With black and white you can debug better the range.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi I've updated the question with further testing results.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi That could be a lead, i'll have to check on it later today, i think their min/max values for LAB/XYZ might be different from my own.

Answer (score 0):

I have not parsed all your code, but an issue in your first code block, in the function **RGBToXYZ**

```
    X = (((X * 0.4124) + (Y * 0.3576) + (Z * 0.1805)) * 100.0)
    Y = (((X * 0.2126) + (Y * 0.7152) + (Z * 0.0722)) * 100.0)
    Z = (((X * 0.0193) + (Y * 0.1192) + (Z * 0.9505)) * 100.0)

    Return New XYZ(X, Y, Z)
```

You do the matrix for X, then use X *again* for the matrix for Y... but now X is at the new value! This is not a place to be skimpy on variables.

This should be instead something like this:

```
    Dim Xout, Yout, Zout As New Double

    Xout = ((X * 0.4124) + (Y * 0.3576) + (Z * 0.1805))
    Yout = ((X * 0.2126) + (Y * 0.7152) + (Z * 0.0722))
    Zout = ((X * 0.0193) + (Y * 0.1192) + (Z * 0.9505))

    Return New XYZ(Xout, Yout, Zout)
```

Also, I suggest keeping XYZ as a 0.0-1.0 range.

#### And for other things:

**LABToXYZ** is missing a needed illuminant conversion. It needs to return:

```
    X = (X * 0.95047)
    Z = (Z * 1.08883)
```

And then **XYZtoLAB** has:

```
    X = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))
    Y = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))
    Z = ((XYZ.X / 95.047) + (XYZ.Y / 100) + (XYZ.Z / 108.883))
```

Which is just making X Y and Z all the same...

Should be (assuming keeping XYZ as 0-1):

```
    X = (XYZ.X / 0.95047)
    Y = (XYZ.Y)
    Z = (XYZ.Z / 1.08883)
```

I just realized that you solved your own question — I'll leave this here though in case someone runs across it in search of similar answers.